Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>' Error 18456 On Deploy Database
From SSMS 2017 I right click the database, then select Tasks->Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL database.
In the Wizard Deployment Settings screen, I click "Connect" and log in to my Azure SQL Server:

Then I click "Next" and get this error:

This question explains the need to grant the user access to the database. But we are creating a new database here.
Update
I am connecting as the admin

Under Access control (IAM) -> Check access -> View my access I can see that I have Owner as a current role assignment
However when I click Eligible assignments I see

Activate a role to perform operations that require elevated
permissions. The role will remain active for a limited time.

and

The tenant needs to have Microsoft Entra ID P2 or Microsoft Entra ID
Governance license.


Ensure you user has necessary permissions to create database.


According to the  MS document

CREATE DATABASE  permissions are necessary. To create a database a login must be either the server admin login (created when the Azure SQL Database logical server was provisioned), the Microsoft Entra admin of the server, a member of the dbmanager database role in  master

The user who you provided is not having the necessary permissions to create database. That may be the reason to get above error. If you are using Entra user to login to SQL server, make sure your Entra user is set as server admin, otherwise set server admin as shown below in SQL server:

If the user is from external provider, add  dbmanager  role to the user in master db using below command:
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER <user>;


Then you will be able to deploy the database successfully as shown below:

Deployed database:

Note: Use latest version of SSMS i.e. SSMS v20.2, it will work.

Thank you. I am logged in as the server owner.

While using with server admin to login are you getting the same error?

Yes I am server admin.

Once try with latest version of SSMS, it may be the reason to get the error. I tried with latest version of SSMS, it worked well without any error.

Thank you. You ar right. I installed SSMM v20.2 and it works.  Can you put this in the answer please so I can accept it.

@Kristen added it in answer.
